# I can't find logical error in allocating memory and using it

Tags: c

I'm learning memory in C.
I'm trying to save prime numbers in pointer prime_numers.
But It didn't work.
I'm so sorry that I can't explain more because my English skill is too short.
Please Give help to this struggling student.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int Modulation(unsigned int);

int main()
{
    int *prime_numbers;
    int a = 1;
    prime_numbers = &a;
    int count = 2;
    int p_count = 1;

    int num = 10;

    while(count<=num)
    {
        if(Modulation(count) == 1)
        {
            prime_numbers = malloc(sizeof(int));
            printf("this is count %d\n", count);
            printf("this is prime_numbers + p_count %d\n", prime_numbers+p_count);
            printf("this is p_count %d\n\n", p_count);
            *(prime_numbers+p_count) = count;
            p_count += 1;
        }
        count += 1;
    }

    for(int i=0 ; i<p_count ; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", *(prime_numbers+i));
    }
    printf("\n\nThis is p_count %d", p_count);
    free(prime_numbers);
    return 0;
}

int Modulation(unsigned int num)
{
    unsigned int count = 2;
    while(count < num)
    {
        if(num%count == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        count += 1;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `prime_numbers` needs to point to enough memory to store `p_count` ints, but it only ever points to a memory location big enough to store 1 int. Maybe `prime_numbers = malloc(num * sizeof(int))` just after you initialize `num`?

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating for only one element. You can use `realloc` to glow previously allocated array.

Also using `%d` to print pointers will invoke *undefined behavior*. To print pointers via `printf()`, you should cast the pointer to `void*` and use `%p`.

Fixed code (error checking is omitted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int Modulation(unsigned int);

int main()
{
    int *prime_numbers = malloc(sizeof(int));
    int a = 1;
    prime_numbers[0] = a;
    int count = 2;
    int p_count = 1;

    int num = 10;

    while(count<=num)
    {
        if(Modulation(count) == 1)
        {
            prime_numbers = realloc(prime_numbers, sizeof(int) * (p_count + 1));
            printf("this is count %d\n", count);
            printf("this is prime_numbers + p_count %p\n", (void*)(prime_numbers+p_count));
            printf("this is p_count %d\n\n", p_count);
            *(prime_numbers+p_count) = count;
            p_count += 1;
        }
        count += 1;
    }

    for(int i=0 ; i<p_count ; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", *(prime_numbers+i));
    }
    printf("\n\nThis is p_count %d", p_count);
    free(prime_numbers);
    return 0;
}

int Modulation(unsigned int num)
{
    unsigned int count = 2;
    while(count < num)
    {
        if(num%count == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        count += 1;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

I fixed only undefined behaviors, but your code have another logical error: `1` is in the array `prime_numbers`, but `1` is not a [prime number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number).